# MVP, WinForms, Unit Testing, Moq, NUnit: Verify that event handlers have been added to a dependency

Tags: c#, winforms, unit-testing, moq, mvp

I have presenter, view and model.
View doesn't know presenter.
Presenter orchestrates everything and knows about the view only through the interface:

```
public interface ISuspiciousListManagementView
{

    void ShowMessageBox(MessageBoxButtons messageBoxButtons, string message, string caption, EMessageBoxIcons icon);

    void ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner);
    object AllTypesDataSource { get; set; }
    SuspiciousListType SelectedType { get; set; }
    event EventHandler SelectedTypeChanged;
    string FilePath { get; set; }

    bool ShowOnlyActive { get; set; }
    object AllHistoryAvailableTypesDataSource { get; set; }
    SuspiciousFilteredListType SelectedHistoryType { get; set; }
    event EventHandler SelectedHistoryTypeChanged;

    object HistoryDataGridSource { get; set; }

    event EventHandler SelectedShowOnlyActiveChanged;

    ICommand BrowseFileCommand { get; set; }
    ICommand UploadCommand { get; set; }
    ICommand RefreshCommand { get; set; }

}
```

Presenter holds method Init:

```
 public async Task Init()
    {
        _view.AllTypesDataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SuspiciousListType));
        _view.AllHistoryAvailableTypesDataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SuspiciousFilteredListType));
        _view.SelectedTypeChanged += OnSelectedTypeChanged;
        _view.SelectedHistoryTypeChanged += OnSelectedHistoryTypeChanged;
        _view.SelectedShowOnlyActiveChanged += OnSelectedShowOnlyActiveChanged;
        _view.HistoryDataGridSource = await GetFilterHistoryItems();
    }
```

and fileld:

```
  private readonly ISuspiciousListManagementView _view;
```

That's injected through constructor.

I need to verify that these code line have been run:

```
    _view.SelectedTypeChanged += OnSelectedTypeChanged;
    _view.SelectedHistoryTypeChanged += OnSelectedHistoryTypeChanged;
    _view.SelectedShowOnlyActiveChanged += OnSelectedShowOnlyActiveChanged;
```

I want to run something like that:

```
 [Test]
    public async void Presenter_Verify_HistoryDataGridSource_assigned_Test()
    {
        await _presenter.Init();
       _viewMock.Verify(dp => dp.SelectedHistoryTypeChanged != null);//Compilation error
    }
```

How can I test that event handlers have been added?
What's wrong with my design?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: What mocking-framework do you use?

Comment: Moq.
I've Updated the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mocking EventHandler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020511/mocking-eventhandler)

Comment: I don't think so.
As far as I understand, there is a question how to test event raising. 
I just need to verify that this code line:
 _view.SelectedTypeChanged += OnSelectedTypeChanged;
Has been executed.

Answer (score 1):

In case of "auto" event, like this:

```
class Test {
    public event Action MyEvent;
}
```

you can get invocation list via reflection:

```
var eventField = test.GetType().GetField(nameof(test.MyEvent), BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var eventDelegate = eventField.GetValue(test);
//either get invocation list or just compare eventDelegate with null
var invocationList = eventDelegate != null ? ((Delegate)eventDelegate).GetInvocationList() : new Delegate[0];
bool anySubscribers = invocationList.Length > 0;
```

That is because compiler expands `MyEvent` to (very roughly) this:

```
class Test {
    private Action MyEvent;

    public event Action MyEvent
    {
        add { Delegate.Combine(this.MyEvent, (Delegate) value);}
        remove { Delegate.Remove(this.MyEvent, value); }
    }
}
```

And we can get value of that private (compiler-generated) field.

In case event is implemented explicitly:

```
class Test {        
    public event Action MyEvent
    {
        add
        {
            // do something

        }
        remove
        {
            // do something else                
        }
    }
}
```

You cannot do this, because might not be even a concept of subscriber - `add` and `remove` can perform arbitrary actions. But that is most likely not your case.

Comment: Understood.
Do I need to test it through "another side"?

Comment: You can test via reflection as shown, because explicit events are very rare, and even if so happens you will use that code with such event - test will fail and you will not miss the problem.

Comment: This idea worked for me, however it doesn't match to my implementation.
Thank you anyway!

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't match to my implementation."?

Comment: In even handler inside of presenter I have casting. This casting fails. Hence I need to change my implementation for a little bit to apply it.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: To explain that I need to show my previous code and new code after refactoring, and it's not relevant any more, because I found a solution owing to your example and others code segments.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of verifying that those code lines have been run, you can also construct a presenter with a view mock, raise events with the mocked view and verify the effect of event handlers on the presenter. This in fact should be how you test the presenter in the first place. It test both that the events are subscribed, and that the handlers are doing what they are supposed to do.